# How to explode() value and save it in a variable?

Tags: php, mysql

Right now I'm working on a new homepage for a museum, and I have to use the old database (because it has over 70k entries).

My job now is to change the values in the "dias" table (supporter row) from full names of the supporters to their IDs (supporter table).

Right know I'm using this code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT pate FROM dias");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
            $pate = explode(" ", print_r($row[0]));
    echo "<br>";
    }
```

If I now put in `$pate[0]`, I only get "1" as output (along with the names from the print_r).

**My question is:**
How can I split the names and save them seperately in a variable, because I think I need this to be able to compare the names with the one in the supporter table and to write the ids in the supporter row in the "dias" table.

If you need more infomration, feel free to ask.

Comment: Why are you using `print_r`? What's the raw value of `$row`?

Comment: mayb u are looking for list() and explode()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`explode` needs a string as the second argument, but you are taking the return value of `print_r`, which is `true` in this case. Just take $row[0] and you should have an array of your data in `$pate`.

Try printing `$pate` after that.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT pate FROM dias");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        $pate = explode(" ", $row[0]);
        print_r($pate)
        echo "<br>";
}
```

After that continue :).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are talking about List() function.  list() will enable you explode into variables like;

```
$address ="Benson Bush|4545547 | living in California" ;

list($name ,$code , $description) = explode("|", $address);

echo $name."<br>";
echo $code."<br>";
echo $description."<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT pate FROM dias");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
            $pate = explode(" ", $row[0]);
print_r($pate);
    echo "<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this *after* you've received the data - do it from your query by using [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(pate, ' ', 1) FROM dias
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT pate FROM dias");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
    print_r($data);
    echo "</br>";
}
print_r($data);
```

If you would like to stored value in variable then you can use extract function also.